# How do you compare two fields in Mongo while performing an operation on one of them?

Tags: mongodb

I have two fields, one is lowercase, and the other is all caps. I want to be able to compare them, after the second field has been made all lower case. I know a normal comparison would be:

```
db.collection.find({$where: "this.name1 == this.name2"})
```

Where `name1` is "John" and `name2` is "JOHN" (for example). 
How do I make `name2` lowercase so that they compare correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```
db.collection.find({$where: "this.name1.toLowerCase() == this.name2.toLowerCase()"})
```

I just tested this and it seems that if some of the documents are missing the fields used in `$where` clause then the query will return an error.

In case you aren't sure that all records will contain the compared fields then your query should also check if the fields exists:

```
db.collection.find({
    name1: {$exists: true},
    name2: {$exists: true},
    $where: "this.name1.toLowerCase() == this.name2.toLowerCase()"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a common operation, I would strongly advise against using `$where` and instead altering the documents to contain the precomputed value of the comparison:

```
{
    "name1": "John",
    "name2" : "JOHN",
    "cmp" : true
}
```

or

```
{
    "name1": "John",
    "name2" : "SAM",
    "cmp" : false
}
```

`$where` uses server-side Javascript, which will be an order of magnitude slower than other operations on the server.

Comment: This is a smart way of doing it! Thanks